# Does a callback passed to CancellationToken.Register cause synchronous waits?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

If I attach a callback to `CancellationToken.Register`, is execution of that callback handled synchronously (and therefore blocks) at the point the `CancellationToken` is cancelled? Or is it handled asynchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cancellation callback is always executed synchronously, in the thread that called `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`. If you can't afford to block, you need to call `Cancel` in a separate thread.

If that bothers you, I opened an issue to provide async cancellation: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23716

It hasn't gained much traction so far though.

Comment: Would you opt to use `Task.Run` to call `Cancel()`, or in the supplied callback (`Register(() => Task.Run(MyCallback())`)?

Comment: @James I think it's `Cancel` that should be called in a `Task.Run`. If you try to solve it at the callback level, you risk missing one (as you don't necessarily control the code that is going to use your token)